# many buttons and autolayout

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, autolayout

Here is my situation. I want to put many buttons in one view, like a calculator application. It should work with different screen size, 3.5inch and 4inch.

I hope 4inch view has larger buttons and 3.5inch view has smaller buttons with appropriate
spacing.

However, I have several issues.

1) When the view has many components and constraints, Xcode is significantly slow. So editing such view is quite time consuming process.  Also it is not easy to edit such view.

2) There are too many constraints and I want to minimize number of constraints. However, I can delete some, but can not delete other.

So what is the best practice for such case? Writing code is better?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would do as much as you can using IB. In your case, since it looks like your a limited by your computer's performance, I would suggest doing your constraints programmatically using the visual format language.

Comment: Thanks. My application needs nearly 50 buttons. Usually IB generated four constraints for a button. It is far beyond manageable. Now I am researching visula format and collection view method.